# How do you control a 12V PC fan from a Raspberry Pi?

Tags: pi-3, gpio

I just got an old PC fan from a computer that was taken apart at my school and I want to try and figure out how to make it turn on using the GPIO ports on a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B. It is a DC 12V fan and it has three wires. One red, one black, and one yellow. I looked it up online and it looks like the black is ground and the red is the 12V- wire. Is there any way I could control this straight from the GPIO pins. Thanks.

Edit: Is there a way that I can control the fan directly from the GPIO without a motor driver chip?

Comment: the fan is a motor ... google  `RPi control motor`

Comment: what do you mean by that?

Comment: the yellow wire could be used as a control line to control the fan speed or it could be a tachometer signal to read the fan speed  .............. the fan voltage is probably printed on the fan itself

Comment: yeah it is a dc 12v motor

Comment: I made an edit to the original question that might clarify my question. ^___^

Comment: with that colour scheme, the yellow is more likely to be `sense` rather than `control` (or `tach`, rather than `pwm`) @jsotola - and by more likely, I mean, if it's a PC fan it's 99.999% likely

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to control safely any motor directly from a Pi GPIO.  You always need to use a motor driver board or the equivalent in discrete components.

1. The Pi GPIO are all 3V3.
2. A Pi GPIO can only supply a few milliamps of power (say 20 milliamps).
3. The [back EMF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counter-electromotive_force) generated by a collapsing motor field can destroy the GPIO and the Pi.

You can buy a suitable L9110S or L298N based board quite inexpensively from the likes of eBay.

You could use a discrete motor driver chip such as the L293D or for limited control (not direction) a ULN2803A.

You could implement your own circuitry with suitable transistors, resistors, and diodes.

Comment: The pins on a raspberry pi can be up to 5v though and it is right next to a gnd  pin

Comment: @rrr Yes, you can power a small motor from the Pi's voltage rails.  The motor will be running whenever the Pi is powered.  That wouldn't be counted as motor control though.

Comment: if i wanted it to be on whenever the pi was on could i attach the red wire to the 5V and the black wire to the ground pin and not use the signal wire? Would that be safe?

Comment: That would be fine (as long as the motor doesn't need more current than the Pi can supply, if it does the Pi will keep rebooting).

Comment: it needs 12V but it should be able to run off of 5V right? It just wouldn't spin as fast?

Comment: Impossible to say.  I have a 12V PC fan which does spin at 5V, albeit very slow.  Try and see.

Comment: Do you think it would be dangerous for my pi?

Comment: No I do not it would be dangerous.  However as in all answers it is your Pi and your risk.

Comment: Yeah ok I'm not gonna try it because it's the only one i have

Answer (score 2):

Go in raspi config through terminal.
Then in performance analysis.
There you will get a option of cooling fan.
Just enable it and connect the yellow wire to GPIO 14 (pin 8).
Pi will automatically control it's speed according to temperature.